# editar variables en los templates django {{}}

Tags: django, django-templates

Soy novato en django y tengo una duda sobre las variables que se muestran en un templates, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
   {% for category in links %}
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{category.get_url}}">{{category.cat_name}}</a> 
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

quiero capitalizar **category.cat_name**, pero al momento de hacer un **category.cat_name.capitalize()** aparece un error, ¿debería modificar esto en otra parte?

debería aplicarse en mi archivo context_proccesors.py

```
from .models import Category

def menu_links(request):
    links = Category.objects.all()
    return dict(links=links)
```

tengo esto en el modelo, también tengo otra duda de novato, ¿Debería hacer las validaciones en el modelo?

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    cat_description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    cat_slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/categories', blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_name
```

Saludos a todos y agradezco sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

En las templates no puedes usar `()` para llamar a funciones.
En concreto para poner en mayúsculas un texto te recomiendo utilizar las `templatetags` básicas de Django, que puedes ver aquí:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#upper

Te debería quedar algo así:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
   {% for category in links %}
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ category.get_url }}"> 
         {{ category.cat_name|upper }}
       </a> 
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias daniel

Comment: Un placer, Omaro. Si te ha servido la respuesta, la puedes marcar como correcta.

Comment: Por complementar la respuesta: las validaciones deberías hacerlas en el `forms.py`. Es ahí donde tienes el estandar `clean_{field}` o `clean` para revisar que todo lo que recibas es correcto.

Comment: gracias daniel, no me deja puntuar porque soy nuevo en la plataforma